# Fix time differences in Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10, time

I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Every time after switching between the two systems the clock time seems to be off. Can somebody please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: By default Ubuntu expects the system block to use UST/UTC/GMT/Zulu time (ie. the same anywhere in the world), where as windows defaults to local time (and needs changing every time you cross timezones).  You can tell either to use the other default (internet/UST/UTC/GMT/Zulu time is easiest, esp. if you travel!)

Comment: Read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts